# How can I implement a ceaser cipher that stays within the bounds of the alphabet in C

Tags: c

I have the following problem:

I would to implement a ceaser cipher which works mostly, but when I reach the end of the alphabet it goes beyond the alphabet which I assume is due to the ascii values.

for example:
if I insert a `k` and use the key `35` I get a `H` but it should wrap around in the lowercase letters and produce a `b`.
It also sometimes produces a punctuation mark or something else like `<` which I do not want.

The code responsible for the encryption is

```
encripted_text = (plain_text + key - 97)%26 +97;
```

am I missing something to make it wrap around and only stay in the alphabet.

Example run of program:

```
char plain_text = 'k';
int k = 35;
char encripted_text = '\0';

encripted_text = (plain_text + key - 97)%26 + 97;

printf("%c", encripted_text);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can u show the inputs and outputs of your problem?

Comment: ok `plain_text' = 'k'; and encrypted_text = 'H'; with  key = 35;

Comment: You should edit your question to add more information, not post it as comments.

Comment: How is your output be capital 'H'..Please,tell your ciphering process?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `encripted_text` and `plain_text` are both char variables (1 byte), you have to decide a formula making sure that even when the result wraps around a *valid* output character is calculated.

How to do that? It depends on what are valid chars for you! In some cases you can simply rely on how characters are mapped in ASCII code, but I want suggest you a general solution that you will be able to translate in your specific requirement.

This general solution consists in defining an array with the accepted alphabet, and translate the input character to one of the characters in it.

For example:

```
char alphabet[] = { 'a','A','b','B','c','C' }; //just an example
char input_char = 'k';
int key = 35;
char encripted_char = '\0';

encripted_char = alphabet[(input_char + key - 97)%(sizeof(alphabet))];

printf("%c", encripted_char );
```

Summarizing: the formula doesn't calculate **directly** the encrypted char, but the index of the accepted alphabet array normalized using `%` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I got the right output with the same logic @nad34. In fact, I correctly got the output as 't' for 'k'. It shouldn't and won't give a 'b'.
Your code is having the right logic, except for a few slight errors.

I don't know why you're using a string here, but since you are anyway, this -> `char plain_text[] = 'k';` should instead be `char plain_text[] = "k";` ==> **Note the double quotes**.

`int k = 35;` should be `int key = 35;`, since you have used the variable name `key` and not k.

Logicwise it is right, and it will give you the right output.

You can check out the execution of the same code [here](https://repl.it/repls/CulturedArtisticObservation).